# Connection refused by Android SDK and AVD manager

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to set up Eclipse 3.5 with the Android plugin. I followed all the steps and everything installed fine. However, running the SDK and AVD Manager throws a connection refused error. I am behind a firewall at work and can not bypass it.

How can I install the Android platforms without using the manager?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this page: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Check the Troubleshooting ADT Installation section. You will find the instruction on how to set up a proxy in Eclipse or download the plug-in directly.

Comment: the ADT is downloaded and installed properly. However, it is the "SDK Setup.exe" and throws the error. I only want to download the platforms (2.2 and 2.1). Everything else seems to be installed correctly.

Comment: Eclipse uses the proxy automatic configuration correctly. But the other tool that downloads plugin components (SDK Setup.exe) seems to have no way to use the automatic configuration that Eclipse and IE are both using.